# Python Tkinter make the return key do a different function if pressed 2 times in a row

Tags: python, tkinter, double-click

I'm writing a calculator and I bound the return key to give me the answer to the problem. The problem is that when I press the return key 2 times in a row, the operation does not continue but it thinks that my answer is now the second number that I entered. Thus I want to create a new function that when I press the return key twice, a new thing happens. The problem is that I don't know how. I've tried making it a double click but a double click is only when the button is pressed 2 times over a short period of time. For me, I want a new function to happen when the return key is pressed 2 times in a row, even if it is clicked 1 minute after. Any help is appreciated. If you have another solution to this, that would be also great. Here's how the return key does for only addition:

```
def key_equal(event):

    second_number = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    
    if b == 9:
        global sum
        sum = f_num + float(second_number)

        if int(sum) == sum:
            sum = int(sum)

        
        e.insert(0, sum)
```

Comment: well just count the return key presses and when the counter reaches two execute the other function and reset the counter

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable to count how many times it occurs.

```
count = 0

def myfunc(event):
    global count

    if count >= 2:
        onefunc()
        count = 0
        return

    else:
        myotherfunc()
        count += 1
```

This counts how many times the return key was pressed, and if it is 2 it sets the variable back to 0, and something else takes place.